How to make this tree-generating React hook more concise?
This hook creates a tree structure that resembles folders. You can put any item in these folders. Their ids will be stored in fileIds. If there are no folders (in local storage), a default folder will be created:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Folder } from '@repo/ui/types';
import { getAllFileIds } from '@repo/ui/helpers';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

type FilterFunction<T> = (item: T) => boolean;

const defaultRootFolder = [
  {
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: 'Root',
    folders: [],
    fileIds: [],
  },
];

interface UseDirProps<T> {
  items: T[];
  storageKey?: string;
  filterFn?: FilterFunction<T>;
}

export function useDir<T extends { id: string }>({
  items,
  storageKey = 'folders',
  filterFn = () => true,
}: UseDirProps<T>) {
  const [filedItems, setFiledItems] = useState<T[]>([]);
  const [folders, setFolders] = useState<Folder[]>([]);
  const [foldersLoaded, setFoldersLoaded] = useState(false);

  function handleClickFolder(folder: Folder) {
    const allFileIds = getAllFileIds(folder);
    const filteredByFolder =
      items?.filter((item: T) => allFileIds.includes(item.id)) || [];
    setFiledItems(filteredByFolder);
  }

  function initRootFolder(currentUserItems: T[]) {
    setFolders((prevFolders: Folder[]) => {
      const updatedFolders = [...prevFolders];
      const rootFolder = updatedFolders.find(
        (updatedFolder) => updatedFolder.id === folders[0]?.id,
      );

      if (rootFolder) {
        rootFolder.fileIds = currentUserItems.map((item) => item.id);
      }

      return updatedFolders;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const savedFolders =
      typeof window !== 'undefined' ? localStorage.getItem(storageKey) : null;
    if (savedFolders) {
      const parsedFolders = JSON.parse(savedFolders);
      setFolders(
        parsedFolders.length === 0 ? defaultRootFolder : parsedFolders,
      );
    } else {
      setFolders(defaultRootFolder);
    }
    setFoldersLoaded(true); // Folders have been loaded from local storage
  }, [storageKey]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (items.length && foldersLoaded) {
      const currentUserItems = items.filter((item: T) => filterFn(item));
      setFiledItems(currentUserItems);
      if (folders.length === 1 && folders[0]?.fileIds.length === 0) {
        initRootFolder(currentUserItems);
      }
    }
  }, [items, foldersLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && folders.length > 0) {
      localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(folders));
    }
  }, [folders, storageKey]);

  return {
    folders,
    setFolders,
    handleClickFolder,
    filedItems,
  };
}

Usage:
const {
  folders,
  setFolders,
  handleClickFolder,
  filedItems: filedIcons,
} = useDir({
  items: icons || [],
  storageKey: 'iconTree',
  filterFn: filterByAuthor,
});

Any way to remove redundancy and/or improve readability?
